# Please help! I am having difficulties about this proof about the volume of a ball.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Serge Lang defines a ball to be:

> the set of all points in space whose distance from P is less than or equal to r

Next, he writes a theorem and then a proof about it:

> Theorem 9-9: The volume of a ball of radius r is $$\frac{4}{3}πr^2$$

> Proof: Suppose we know the volume V of a ball of radius 1. Then by Theorem 9-7 the volume of the ball of radius r is equal to $$Vr^3.$$ So it suffices to prove that the volume of the ball of radius 1 is $$\frac{4π}{3}$$

To give context, theorem 9-7 is:

> The volume V of the cone is given by the formula $$V=\frac{1}{3}Bh$$
> Where B is the area of the base.

My question is how did Mr. Lang arrive about $Vr^3$ using theorem 9-7? I've been reading and searching for answers but to no avail. Please help!

Edit: I think it has something to do about dilations, but I am really not sure if what I think it is right.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. I don't know what text you're referring to, but I guess Mr. Lang stated a wrong theorem. Instead, he likely meant to reference one dealing with the volumes of similar objects (i.e., ones which are "dilated", as your edit indicates), such as explained in [Ratios of sides, of areas, and of volumes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry)#Ratios_of_sides,_of_areas,_and_of_volumes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your problem statement. The volume of a ball is $\frac{4}{3} \pi r^3.$

John already made it clear in these comments. Let me elaborate on his comment a little bit.

Consider $2$-dimensional objects, say triangle. Suppose you have two similar triangles $T_1 $ and $T_2.$ Let $r$ be the ratio of "similar sides" of the triangles. Then $\frac{\Delta T_1}{\Delta T_2} = r^2.$ Here $\Delta T$ means the area of the triangle $T.$ This is an easy exercise of basic Euclidean geometry. Note that this same relationship is true for two similar squares, circles, and so on. In general, it's true for any two similar $2$-dimensional objects. Now, consider $3$-dimensional objects such as cubes and balls. For two similar cubes, it clear that $\frac{V_1} {V_2} = r^3$ where $V_1$ and  $V_2$ indicate the volume of the cubes and $r$ is the ratio of side length. This is surely true for similar balls/solid spheres. Note that any two balls are similar. "Similarity ignores sizes." Therefore, to find the volume of a ball of radius $1$ is enough to compute the volume of a ball with any radius. In fact, this same idea is applicable to higher-dimensional objects.

Comment: It all makes clear sense now. Thank you for taking the time to answer